# How to disable registration for public side of a web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I have simple web application on .NET Core 2.2. I would like to have only authorization for public side of application. You can ask me "where I will take new users for my system if I will have only authorization?". I would like to create users manually. With my point of view, this task is very simple. Any web-framework has some functional for this. But I can't find civilized way to implement it for .NET Core!

So, actually I have pretty ugly way to make it. I just added this middleware:

Sample form `Startup.cs` file

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // disable registration if not Local environment
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (env.IsEnvironment("Local"))
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("Register") ||
                        context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("ForgotPassword"))
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Registration is closed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await next.Invoke();
                    }    
                }
            });
```

As you can see, if the environment is local - I can register a new user. Else - registration is closed.

I knew that this way is bad and I had started research how to make it better. My plan was overwrite `AcountController` and user additional conditions for registration method. I know that there is this instrument [ms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2). It can generate identity scaffolding. But it can't generate `AccountController`! Only views. I tried to make `AccountController` manually, but without success. I will show you:

```cs
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

I expected that the above code switch off login and makes for me 404 instead of login. But login works.

This task is easy: to make web application with authorization but without registration (only developer can add new users). How to make it for .Net Core?

I put here Identity settings:

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15207#issuecomment-544648638

Shortly speak, I just need to modify `Register.cshtml.cs` file. It's here:

[image]

My modification is:

```
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        if (!_hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Local"))
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");
        }

        return RedirectToPage("/Account/Register");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid && _hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Local"))
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

Now I can register a new user if my environment is `Local`. But it's not very securely. Better way is to make simple console application for register new users.

> If you mean to be able to register users during local development, you can alternatively write a very simple console app that connects to the DB and populates the initial list of users. After all, as you mention registration is not part of your app, so if you reduce the surface attack area that's definitely better.